# Firestore security rules - read allowed only for Story members

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-security

I've read a lot lately about firestore but I'm still struggling with one thing.

I have Story documents in my firestore:

```
story: {
  name: 'James',
  members: {
    'WeWF34RFD23RF23': 'viewer'
  }
}
```

members property on this document is a map, where key is uid and value is user's role.

I use AngularFireAuth for auth and AngularFirestore to query db.

THE PROBLEM

When I query for documents I get permission error even though I query only for docs I have permissions to read.

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private fAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.collection = db.collection<StoryId>('story', ref => ref.where('name', '==', 'James'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stories$ = this.collection.snapshotChanges().pipe( ... )
  }
```

There can be multiple James stories and all of them have my uid in its members map. There are also stories that have different name and don't have my uid in it's members map. By this query I want to get all of James stories which results in error but when I query for single document ('story/{story_id}') all works fine.

Here are my security rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /story/{story} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
      allow create;

    }
  }
}
```

Maybe the issue is that when AngularFirestore queries for collection it needs access rights to whole collection to return only the values that I can access? If so how can I get only documents that I have access rights to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

The problem was If you query only for stories with *name = James* then firestore will check if you can read (exactly it's called list in firestore) all of documents even though I'm asking only for James.

What's the solution then?

The best idea is to keep vulnerable data in **subcollection** like below

```
story: {
  name: 'James',
  superPrivateData: {
    ...here goes subcollection
  }
}
```

But be careful, since map is NOT the same as subcollection.
More on differences between map and subcollection you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s)

Hope it will help someone in the future!